# Can't assign a child entry to a parent entry in database tables

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

I have 2 tables in a database: `Albums`(parent table in one-to-many relationships) and `Songs`(child table):

Albums:

[image]

Songs:

[image]

Here's the database Context class and `Album` and `Song` model classes:

```
namespace SQLite_test2
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Song> songs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder dbContextOptionsBuilder)
        {
            dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source =database.db");
        }
    }

    public class Album
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Artist { get; set; }
        public List<Song> Songs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Song
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Songname { get; set; }

        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public Album Album { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I assign a parent to a `Song` entry it works fine:

```
namespace SQLite_test2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using ( var databaseContext = new DatabaseContext() )
            {
                Album MyAlbum = new Album() { Title = "Reign in Blood", Artist = "Slayer" };
                Song MySong = new Song() { Songname = "Angel of Death" };
                
                // assigning relationships, works OK.
                MySong.Album = MyAlbum;
                databaseContext.albums.Add(MyAlbum);
                databaseContext.songs.Add(MySong);

                databaseContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to do it the other way around, by trying to add a child to a parent I get an exception:

```
namespace SQLite_test2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using ( var databaseContext = new DatabaseContext() )
            {
                Album MyAlbum = new Album() { Title = "Reign in Blood", Artist = "Slayer" };
                Song MySong = new Song() { Songname = "Angel of Death" };

                //System.NullReferenceException: 
                //"Object reference not set to an instance of an object
                //SQLite_test2.Album.Songs.get вернул null.
                MyAlbum.Songs.Add(MySong);
                databaseContext.albums.Add(MyAlbum);
                databaseContext.songs.Add(MySong);

                databaseContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect I should have made a change in the `Albums` table to reflect the existence of `Songs` list in the `Album` class, but no tutorials I saw mention anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because the Songs collection on Album is not initialized. You're trying to add a song to a non-existent collection.

The quick fix in Album is:

```
public List<Song> Songs { get; set; } = new List<Song>();
```

For child collections you should always initialize them so that new entities are in a state that related children can be added. They should also be declared them as `virtual ICollection<Child>` rather than `List<Child>`. `virtual` both enables lazy loading (if needed) and allows for the proxies for change tracking to work fully.

```
public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; } = new List<Song>();
```

Comment: Interesting! This is not well explained in [the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)